# convert multiple tuple into list

Tags: python, list, tuples, python-itertools

im working with multiple data that i read with for

```
for x in list_data: #i have 3 data inside
    data_file = static/upload_file/'+x
```

for some reason i need to pick a value from each data, i read the data using pandas dataframe, so i always append the value i want to pick from each data to a list that outside the for loop. the result i get is multiple tuple

```
result = [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[...]]
```

i already try using itertools like this

```
result = list(chain(*result))
```

and

```
final_result = []
for t in result:
        for x in t:
            final_result.append(x)
```

the output always like this :

```
[1,2,3,4,5,[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5][..]]]
```

the output that i want is :

```
[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]
```

complete code is like this :

```
resul = []
final_result = []

for x in list_data: #i have 3 data inside
data_file = static/upload_file/'+x

#read_csv~
result.append((some_data))

for t in result:
    for x in t:
        final_result.append(x)
```

how can i convert the multiple tuple into 1 list ? thanks in advance.

Comment: sounds you might want `extend` rather than `append`

Comment: yeah youare right, thanks @alaniwi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add items to the final_result list, use extend rather than append. Here's the difference:

```
res = [1, 2, 3]
res.append([4, 5])
print(res)

[1, 2, 3, [4, 5]]

res = [1, 2, 3]
res.extend([2, 4])
print(res)

[1, 2, 3, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try below code:

```
output_list = []
for i in results:
    if isinstance(i, list):
        output_list.extend(i)
    else:
        output_list.append(i)
```